# Isosceles Trapezoid Diagonal Lengths, sum of bases and field

Tags: geometry

Field of the isosceles trapezoid is **P**.  Sum of the trapezoid bases is **d**. Calculate the diagonal length **p**.

I was thinking to use the formula $P = \frac{p^2}2 sin\alpha$ but I don't have any idea how to get the $\sin \alpha$.

Comment: can you post us a Picture please?

Comment: What to you mean by "field" ?

Answer (score 0):

The formula $P = \frac{p^2}2 sin\alpha$ looks wrong, for example a trapezoid of height $p$ and base $0$ would have a non-zero area.

Area of trapezoid with bases $d_1,d_2$ and height $h$ is $\frac{d_1+d_2}2h$. Since $d_1+d_2=d$ and area is $P$ this gives $$P=\frac d2 h\implies h=\frac{2P}d$$
Now by Pythagoras the diagonal is $\sqrt{(d_1+d_2)^2/4+h^2}=\sqrt{\frac{d^2}4+\frac{4P^2}{d^2}}$